# Read from a .csv, grab the files from a folder and copy to a new folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a batch script to use with Windows command prompt, to read from a `.csv` filename list, grab and select the files from a folder and copy to a new folder:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (theFile.csv) do (
  for /f %%j in ('dir /s /b %theDir%\%%i.*') do (
    copy "%%j" "C:\Data"  
  )
)
```

This command seems to copy but all the files, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [tag:bash] is not the same as [tag:batch-script], so don't confuse them!

Comment: Can you please show what your csv content looks like?

Comment: my csv file is in one column of 1547 different file names

Comment: Please put all relevant information into your question by [edit]ing it! Also please be precise in describing what exactly does not work! Please consider to read [mcve]...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something this, depending on the structure of your csv file:

```
@echo off
set "thedir=\\PC\Users\Salvatore\Desktop\BackupUnlock"
for /f "delims=" %%i in ("C:\Users\Salvatore\Desktop\csv1.csv") do for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s /a-d "%%i"') do copy "%%a" "C:\Data" /Y
```

Comment: my csv file is in one column of 1547 different file names

Comment: \\PC\Users\Salvatore\Desktop\BackupUnlock is the directory where i have to select the files                                                                                                                           C:\Users\Salvatore\Desktop\csv1.csv is my csv file in one column of 1547 different file names

Comment: error: impossible to use the format"path:pattern" with /R